# Iphone App developed with KivyMD Crashing

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I've created a game with KivyMD and currently I am testing it on iOS. I have tested the game on Android and it works flawlessly. The game builds successfully in XCode and once built, the game works fine on an iPhone. However, few days later, something seems to be going wrong and app starts to crash in iPhone. As soon as I launch the game, I see a black screen which appears to be a pre-splash. However, I haven't set a pre-splash for the game. If I rebuild the game in XCode again, it builds successfully with no errors and the app starts to work fine again for few more days and then it starts to crash. Can someone help me with the following?

1. Is there a way to look at the error message in some log file on iPhone when the app crashes?
2. Is there a debugging tool that I can use to troubleshoot when the app crashes?
3. Is there an iOS simulator app that I can use on my iMac to test the app?
4. XCode shows the build log as successful always. So, the app crashing appears to be a run-time error. Unfortunately, I am new to this and needs some help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**:  You'll probably want to find a solution that is specific to Kivy.  This answer may help.  In fact, your question may be considered a duplicate:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27175629/2476389

---

Generally, I recommend Firebase Crashlytics for crash logs.  If a crash occurs in your app, the stack trace and other helpful info will be uploaded to your Firebase console the next time the app is started.  You can see all your crashes in the console.  You will need to follow the instructions to integrate crashlytics into your app and then release a new build, but it's well worth it.  This will allow you to get crash logs from all devices (testers, users, etc).

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics

For crashes you can reproduce on your dev device, you can also retrieve the log directly:

https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=nra79npr

Comment: The app is not using any database.

Comment: @BalajiPooruli Firebase does not require use of a database.  You can just install the Crashlytics module for crash reporting.

Comment: Is there a Python module or API for Firebase Crashlytics?

Comment: @Pyzard I can't find a python integration, which doesn't surprise me, since it targets mobile clients.

Comment: Kivy **is** for Python. You can use Kivy to build applications for Windows, Android, macOS, iOS, and Linux. I've heard about a module called `pyrebase` for using Firebase in Python programs. Do you have any idea if it'll help?

Comment: @Pyzard I'm not familiar with it, but the documentation mentions only auth, database, and storage as supported services.  I don't see Crashlytics mentioned.  

firebase.database() - Database

firebase.storage() - Storage